# Join two worksheets; first contains a list of ranges, second contains data that may fall within in range of the first

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I'm working on combining two excel worksheets. Before I start, I'd like to mention that I also have mysql workbench, so I'm open to working on this issue in either sql or vba (I should learn both). I'm working with .bed files, which are lists of genomic coordinates. In short, the data is indexed by chromosome number (ie:chr2) and then has a numerical start and stop location on the chromosome. These numerical locations can span a large range (ie:100-10,000) or be a single position (ie: 999-1000). I have a list of coordinates that cover a large range, and in a separate file I have a list of single positions.

Example of a file with ranges:

```
chromosome    start   stop
chr1          4561    6321
chr3          9842   11253
```

Example of file with single positions:

```
chromosome   start   stop
chr1          5213   5214
chr3          10254  10255
```

I would like to combine these worksheets such that if a location in my list of single positions is found within the range in my list of ranges, the locations for both are listed in the same row. The lists are 1000s of locations long, so I'd also like this program to loop through every row. Using the example data listed above, I'd like my output to look like the following:

Example of desired output:

```
chromosome  start   stop  chromosome  start  stop
chr1         4561   6321    chr1      5213   5214
chr3         9842  11253    chr3     10254  10255
```

There is a high probability that multiple single positions will fall within a single range, and I would like these to be listed as separate rows.

I appreciate any help I can get! Thank you in advance. I am eager to learn!

Comment: Something like `select a.chromosome, a.start, a stop, b.chromosome, b.start, b.stop from ranges_table a, positions_table b where b.start >= a.start and b.stop <= a.stop` should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic outline which queries two tables on sheets named "Ranges" and "Positions", and outputs the results on a sheet named"Results"

The input tables should have headers, and start in the top-left cell (A1)

```
Sub SqlJoin()

    Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sPath
    Dim sSQL As String, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    sSQL = " select a.chromosome, a.start, a stop," & _
            " b.chromosome, b.start, b.stop " & _
            " from <ranges_table> a, <positions_table> b" & _
            " where b.start >= a.start and b.stop <= a.stop"


    sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "<ranges_table>", _
           Rangename(wb.Worksheets("Ranges").Range("A1").CurrentRegion))

    sSQL = Replace(sSQL, "<positions_table>", _
           Rangename(wb.Worksheets("Positions").Range("A1").CurrentRegion))

    If wb.Path <> "" Then
      sPath = wb.FullName
    Else
      MsgBox "The workbook must be saved first!"
      Exit Sub
    End If

    oConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & sPath & "';" & _
                 "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"

    oRS.Open sSQL, oConn

    If Not oRS.EOF Then
        wb.Worksheets("Results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset oRS
    Else
        MsgBox "No records found"
    End If

    oRS.Close
    oConn.Close

End Sub

Function Rangename(r As Range) As String
    Rangename = "[" & r.Parent.Name & "$" & _
                r.Address(False, False) & "]"
End Function
```

Comment: This code worked well, but I did end up using a program that is much easier - bedtools.